# inserting to data shows an error in sqlite in android

Tags: android, sqlite

i am try to insert user and pass to login table it shows an error, i am passing username,password as construtor to database class. now i want to insert username and password to login page

```
             public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "sample";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String INSPECTION_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS login ("
                        + "username TEXT," + "password TEXT);";



public Database(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS login");

}
 public void insert_datas(String user,String pass,String table_name){
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();//in this line error comes

         ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();

            initialValues.put("user",user);
            initialValues.put("pass",pass);
            long n = db.insert(table_name,user,initialValues);

            System.out.println("n"+n);
            db.close();
    }
```

}

Comment: what type of error you are getting?post your logcat

Comment: 05-09 09:51:23.122: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:118)

Comment: Where you have execute INSPECTION_CREATE (Sql query String)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't created your database... the onCreate method is empty, nor do I see you use your table creation string anywhere else.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(INSPECTION_CREATE);
}
```

Your onUpgrade needs a little help too (it'll delete the table but not re-create it):

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS login");
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Use dbhelper object to get `SqliteDataBase` Object

```
DataBase dbhelper = new Database(context);

SQLiteDatabase db=dbhelper .getWritableDatabase();
```